# Miss-aligned boxes

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to html and I am trying to make a basic web page layout, which was all aligned and looked fine until I started adding content into the boxes. Can anyone please help with this annoying alignment issue I am having at the moment.

[image]

```css
.container {
  /* Auto margins used for centering elements horizontally */
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  /* Box dimensions */
  width: 980px;
  /* Colour of box */
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #81BBC9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  /* Vertical */
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Horizontal */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #81BBC9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  /* Vertical */
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 40px;
  /* Vertical */
}

.content {
  width: 510px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #81BBC9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  /* Vertical */
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 40px;
  /* Vertical */
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <h3>Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Sidebar</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box1">
    <h3>Footer</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "That file isn’t here anymore. Someone might’ve deleted the file or disabled the link."

Comment: Sorry about that I think it was me. It should be working now

Comment: I've edited your code into the question. You should take a look into flexbox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the response. I have heard about flexbox, but this layout is part of my project so I have to use the material we have learnt so far.

Comment: Then you're going to have to use some JavaScript, or set the sidebar and content divs to a fixed height.

Comment: Yeah, without flexbox CSS or JavaScript to set your columns to equal heights, the best you can do is add `vertical-align: top` to `.content` so it's not clinging to the bottom.

Comment: Yes. When using display: inline-block , use vertical-align to align the element as Jon mentioned

Comment: @JonUleis & nejc.m Thank you very much for the response. Cannot believe vertical-align didn't occur to me. Is there also a way to make both boxes match the without the need of a fixed height.

Comment: @hymcode There is. Flexbox, or JavaScript.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, but surely there is a method without Flexbox or JavaScript.

Comment: @hymcode Have fun finding it, then. Flexbox was invented *because* HTML/CSS didn't have a good way of doing this.

Comment: A bit of frustration playing with a solution leads me to conclude: drawing a layout should be done in a graphics program: I suspect when you get to fleshing out your design you won't care too much about those blue boxes. My quick fix recommendation - remove the blue background from content and vertical align top. Really unhelpful I know but try it. If you want though add `display: table-cell` on your `.content` and `.sidebar` and see what that does and see if you can get that to work. Caveats abound I'm sure.

Comment: @wunth Thank you for giving it an attempt. I shall try what you said and see what I make of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update below css.

```
.content {
  width: 510px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #81BBC9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  /* Vertical */
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* Vertical */
}
```